# How can I have my server show some images or movies on startup or in response to user input?

Tags: server

Is there some way to set up a Linux server so that when it turns on it shows my company logo, and then some pics or videos depending on what it senses?

To be more clear, I made a robot with an ARM-based board like RaspberryPi, then installed Ubuntu Server on it. My robot has an LCD. When a user turns on the robot, I want it to show my company logo on the LCD, then wait for user commands and show what user wants (an image or a video).

How is it possible?

I tried this steps:

> Add a custom session by creating a file at `/usr/share/xsessions/metacity-session.desktop`. This file tells the login manager about your session.
>
> Create the file to be executed by the session added in (1) `/usr/local/bin/metacity-session`
>
> Create the user-specific config file `~/.metacity-session`. This file will be executed by the file added in (2). The content should be the program you want to run, followed by an ampersand, for example
>
> ```
> firefox &
> ```

But when I log out and try to log in to the Metacity session, I get a black screen for a second and then the login screen comes back again.

Comment: If your system shows a company logo when it turns on, that's from the UEFI/BIOS and not from Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need a graphics subsytem. Plain old X-Windows will probably do it but you might want a simple window manager like openbox. Then you will need to tell X to output the logo and run your program. Your program then will need to execute the commands to display movies or images as requested. If you have the user log on first or autologin, then such commands can be put in the users local X configuration files. Here are some of the things I did in a Debian system a few years ago:

```
apt-get -y install xorg
apt-get -y  install xloadimage # For xsetbg command
apt-get-y  -y install xdm
apt-get  -y install openbox
apt-get -y feh #  [for displaying pictures]
```

To change login page picture, put pixmap file (.xpm ) in /usr/share/X11/xdm/pixmaps then edit /etc/X11/xdm/Xresources to point to the pixmap file.
To create pixmap from jpg, use site www.online-utility.org/image_converter.jsp or http://www.convertmyimage.com/

The user's .bashrc and .xsession will have to be customized to run your program in a loop. I did everything in shell scripts. You might need to download other utilities depending on what you want to do and how you want it displayed. I used gxmessage to do all the info output and read reply selections.

Edit: I used this same exact application on both 386 and Raspberry Pi systems.

Comment: Hello jpezz and thanks for answer, but before I saw your answer I tried what I wrote in EDIT, from this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30207/debian-based-system-only-one-gui-program-nothing-else

But I have problem again as I wrote above! Is this way different from your suggestion? Do you know why it didn't work?

Comment: @Hisani, I think your problem is in Pam in that the wait then the login screen again indicates it is likely the login failed. I always had two logins - an administrator with a password and a non-administrator with no password. This allowed me to get the non-admin login working BEFORE attempting to run my program, autologout, or add any restriction. You need to get on the system and check the log files to see if the user successfully logged in and, if so, what it did. My point was to show you in general what you need. You will have to debug it step by step.